# Tips for analysing character's role against the novel's general theme?

Tags: characters, theme

I'm answering a few questions based on Atlas Shrugged in the form of an essay, wherein I am required to discuss a particular character and relate his role to the theme of the story.

Kind of clueless. Help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll assume that you have identified the theme (or a theme) of the story...

Here are some questions that might give you some ideas:

- What is the character's role in the story? (How would the story be different if the character were not in it?)
- How do the character's actions demonstrate the theme (or violate it)?
- What are the consequences to the character of acting in accordance with the theme (or of violating it)?
- How do those consequences reinforce the theme, or argue against the theme, or refine the theme and demonstrate its subtlety and nuance?

Comment: That greatly clarifies my task ahead. Thank you so much! :-)